# Как отследить создание объекта Javascript

Tags: javascript, события, объекты

На основе запроса ajax создается объект с определенными параметрами, также висит обработчик событий этого объекта, но так как объект еще не создан, то соответсвенно ругается на это и при возникновении события ничего не срабатывает. У меня есть мысль как то проверить создался ли объект и если да то тогда уже отслеживать событие создаваемого объекта.

Как отследить создание объекта javascript?

Comment: А нельзя сначала создать "пустой" объект (типа `var obj = {};`), чтобы не ругалось. Ну а из ajax ответа просто заносить данные в этот объект?

Comment: не так не хочет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция $.getJSON() является асинхронной. Запрос следует делать так:

```
$.getJSON(url запроса)
    .then(function(data){
        //выполняемый код, когда поступили данные
});
```

На основании этого примените паттерн Наблюдатель. Как вариант.

Comment: так яж говорю ajax $.ajax

Comment: то же самое: методу `.ajax()` передаётся параметром функция, которая вызывается по получении ответа ("success") – где вы и создаёте свой объект. Там же и вешайте на него слушателя событий.

Comment: Почему то я думал что так работать не будет проверил профит :)

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант – добавить посредника (диспетчер), который известен всем, и создаётся с самого начала.

Объект, когда создаётся, шлёт свои события в этот диспетчер.

И обработчик слушает события не у объекта, а у диспетчера.

Посмотрите паттерн [publish/subscribe](http://habrahabr.ru/post/270339/).

Answer (score 0):

А в JavaScript нет чего-то вроде

```
if(object != null) {
    /*объект существует*/
}
```

?